# Graph in WPF using graph# isn't drawn as a chain

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, graph-sharp

I'm using WPF with graph# library and I'm trying to to draw a graph as a linear chain, so I defined some vertices and the edges joining them as

```
new Edge<object>(vertices[i], vertices[i+1])
```

But the problem is that the resulting graph isn't drawn as expected, it's like the following:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1-> 4

In other words, vertex 3 is passing through vertex 1 to reach vertex 4.

Here's the code of the drawing method

```
private void CreateGraphToVisualize()
{
    var g = new BidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>>();

    // add the vertices to the graph
    string[] vertices = new string[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        vertices[i] = i.ToString();
        g.AddVertex(vertices[i]);
    }

    // add edges to the graph
    g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[0], vertices[1]));
    g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[1], vertices[2]));
    g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[2], vertices[3]));
    g.AddEdge(new Edge<object>(vertices[3], vertices[4]));

    GraphToVisualize = g;
}
```

And here's a part of the xaml code related to graph#

```xml
<DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="10,10,13,10">
    <zoom:ZoomControl>
        <graphsharp:GraphLayout x:Name="graphLayout"
                            Graph="{Binding ElementName=root,Path=GraphToVisualize}" 
                            LayoutAlgorithmType="FR" 
                            OverlapRemovalAlgorithmType="FSA"
                            HighlightAlgorithmType="Simple"/>
    </zoom:ZoomControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: I've tried the code you've pasted above and I can't reproduce locally - I get `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4` as expected.

Comment: The code you pasted works correctly. Are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this code and from what I can see there's nothing wrong with it. It may be that some library-references are out of sync (QuickGraph-GraphSharp). I recompiled the Graph#-Controls and fit it all together in the one solution. I removed the Binding in XAML and loaded the graph in the constructor of MainWindow.

The resulting graph that I get from the code is: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3-> 4 and **not**: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1-> 4. You can download the full source-code [here](http://sdrv.ms/WN5Ov5) to see for yourself.

---

*Further References*

- [QuickGraph, Graph Data Structures And Algorithms for .NET](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)
- [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/)